# DFS Replication, Losing folders

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, replication

We lost a lot of folders in one part of our AD.
I tracked down that we get a lot of errormessages about this in this form:

How do we solve this?
Why does this happen?

(Some information edited)

> The DFS Replication service detected that a file was changed on
>   multiple servers. A conflict resolution algorithm was used to
>   determine the winning file. The losing file was moved to the Conflict
>   and Deleted folder.    Additional Information:  Original File Path:
>   E:\IMG\images\sync\domain\yy\xx\promotion\promoSneakers2.jpg  New Name
>   in Conflict Folder:
>   promoSneakers2-{FC3F83F7-ACB7-47C6-83D6-25A7029A73DB}-v7241048.jpg 
>   Replicated Folder Root: e:\IMG File ID:
>   {FC3F83F7-ACB7-47C6-83D6-25A7029A73DB}-v7241048  Replicated Folder
>   Name: img Replicated Folder ID: 4C81ABFB-859B-4F3C-B531-B28501FDBA74 
>   Replication Group Name: company.local\company\img Replication Group
>   ID: BB29461C-2A4C-4FFD-86D5-3477A5588465  Member ID:
>   F590F73B-01ED-49AD-8D60-C5021768AD4E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the folder was changed in (at least) two different places before it was fully replicated throughout your replication topology. When this happens DFS-R uses an algorithm to determine which version should "win". You can prevent this by letting files fully replicated before you modify them at other endpoints.

Comment: Noted, will try to fix this :)